# Getting playlist MPMediaQuery

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get the title of the songs in iphone playlists.

I have tried:

```
MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray *list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[playlistsQuery colkections]; 
MPMediaItem *song = [list objectAtIndex:position];
NSString *title = [song valieForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSLog(@"%@", title);
```

And this title is returning `"(null)"` . The array return 50 itens, the numbe of musica in my iphone

Answer (score 1):

May be ,this will useful for you.
here "playlists" is NSArray.

```
playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    playlists = [playlistsQuery collections];
    NSArray *playlistsss = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];
    for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlistsss) {
        NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
        NSArray *songs = [playlist items];

        for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {

            NSString *songTitle =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
            NSString *str_artistName =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
            NSLog(@"teh artist name is --->%@",str_artistName);
            playlists=[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
            NSLog(@"the songs titles---->%@",array_playList);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a sample code named [AddMusic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), demonstrates the MPMediaPlayer framework. 
Check out this sample code, may help you to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `valueForProperty` instead of `valieForProperty`.